# How to change .profle and have the setting effective without sourcing .profile every time or needing to reboot?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, macos

If it is on the Mac or on Ubuntu, sometimes we have to add a path to `PATH`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725639/npm-install-g-less-does-not-work-eacces-permission-denied

```bsh
# add the following to ~/.profile 
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

However, we have to keep using

```bsh
source ~/.profile
```

in any new Bash window if we don't reboot our machine.  We could put that `PATH` line in `.bashrc`, but it is said that we should only put that `PATH` setting in `.profile`: https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile

So it is a bit of dilemma here: if we don't reboot, we can't have that path in all our Bash shells. But we may not be able to reboot due to many apps running on our machine, and rebooting and retrying is time consuming as well.

Is there a way to make the change, have it in all our Bash shells, but not needing to reboot the computer?

Comment: Why don't you just add your `export PATH=...` to `/etc/profile`?

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` in your `~/.profile` should do the job, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` in your `~/.profile` but then still the effect won't be immediate... besides, I might use Zsh sometimes, so the `.profile` will run and it also source `.bashrc`? that will be not desirable

Answer (score 2):

Your `~/.profile` file is read by the `bash` shell if `~/.bash_profile` does not exist and the shell is a login shell.  Interactive non-login `bash` shells read `~/.bashrc` when starting up.

It is common to  let `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile`) source `~/.bashrc`, especially on systems where `bash` is the only actively used shell (having `~/.profile`, which is read by some non-`bash` shells too, read `~/.bashrc` could cause issues if many different shells are in active use).

To avoid sourcing any of these files in an already running `bash` session, just to add an element to the value of the `PATH` variable, you may run the assignment directly on the command line of the shell:

```bsh
PATH=$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

(Note that using `export` is superfluous both here and when adding it to a startup file  as the `PATH` variable is already an environment variable, unless you have explicitly used `unset` on it.)

There is no other way to modify the `PATH` variable's value in an already active shell session, apart from sourcing the shell initialization file that you just modified (which you wanted to avoid, which is understandable since doing so may also do all sorts of *other* things).

Restarting the shell (not rebooting) should also work, especially if you start your shells as login shells (the terminal emulator can be made to start shells as login shells if they are not login shells by default, as on macOS).

Answer (score 0):

Include your PATH addition in `$HOME/.bash_profile`
which gets executed for every instance of Bash as you launch it...

**More detail:**
Enter `man bash` at the bash prompt,
then to find the specific section:
type `/` and `INVOCATION` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> .

Comment: I think it is not if you add it for the first time and then start a new Bash terminal

Comment: Hmm... not sure I understand that correctly. Note though that the bash has to be a "login shell" - read more about that in `man bash` as show above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can place it inside the PS1, so anytime a shell pops up, you can source the .bashrc or do whatever you like.

Some smart checking is needed, maybe add a line in the .bashrc that puts the timestamp of the .bashrc into a variable? then you can check in the PS1-command if the file has been updated.

Second part might be trickier, if you always append more to the PATH variable, it will grow infinitely with every update. either set a fixed value at the beginning of .bashrc or somehow filter duplicates at the end after all components have been added.

Don't have the time to think aobut this more, but would be great to see if it works. :-)